# Tensorflow 2 batch norm no gradient issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

```
for batch_step, batch in enumerate(self.batch_iterator_train):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
         logits, _ = self.model(batch['images'], is_training=True)
         loss_value = self.loss_fn(labels=batch['labels'], logits=logits)
    grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, self.model.trainable_variables) # use gradient to automatically retrieve gradients of var. wrt loss
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.model.trainable_variables)) # apply one step of gradient descent
```

I'm using the code above to train my model in Tensorflow 2.1.0, but I'm getting the following error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables ['net/block/batch_norm_relu_1/batch_normalization_1/beta:0', .....]
```

Is there an issue with TF 2.10 with batch norm, especifically with the beta parameter? As far as I understand, the beta parameter is used for shifting the batch norm values - so it should be trainable.

UPDATE:
Upon closer inspection, I noticed that about half of my batch norm layers have weights of all 0s.

```
self.model.trainable_variables[17]
Out[63]: 
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
      dtype=float32)>
```

I'm really not sure why though.

Comment: Have you dried pulling line 5 in your code under the `with tf.GradientTape() as tape` scope?

Comment: @prouast Thanks for your response! Yes, I've tried that and still get the same warning. Upon closer inspection, I noticed that my trainable variable weights for some of my batch norm beta values are all 0's. But it's only like that for some of my bath norm layers, roughly half of them

Comment: That's curious. Have your checked whether all layers are connected properly?

Comment: @prouast Ah that's embarrassing, yes you were right. Thank you very much for suggesting that! By the way, though, line 5 should be fine where it's at right? That's how I saw it in the TF tutorials

Comment: No worries, happy to help! Yes if it is like this in the tutorials, then it should be fine.

Comment: So is the problem solved? If not, you should provide the code where you define the model.